# SQL Server deadlock on disjoint sets

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, deadlock

I have the following relatonships

Keyword(1)<--->(n)K2I(n)<--->(1)Clip(n)<--->(1)Media

Namely, We have a set a keywords and a set of clips. Any keywords can be associated to any clips. Several clips can be defined on one media.

I have repeatedly deadlocks with the following graph :

```
deadlock-list
 deadlock victim=process8ba4d8
  process-list
   process id=process8ba4d8 taskpriority=0 logused=2120 waitresource=KEY: 6:72057600639696896 (37001eba95c6) waittime=7593 ownerId=2999710658 transactionname=user_transaction lasttranstarted=2012-03-23T10:13:29.140 XDES=0x2e2395e8 lockMode=U schedulerid=1 kpid=5268 status=suspended spid=295 sbid=0 ecid=0 priority=0 transcount=2 lastbatchstarted=2012-03-23T10:13:29.857 lastbatchcompleted=2012-03-23T10:13:29.857 hostpid=2648 loginname=EVS isolationlevel=read committed (2) xactid=2999710658 currentdb=6 lockTimeout=4294967295 clientoption1=671088672 clientoption2=128056
    executionStack
     frame procname=adhoc line=1 sqlhandle=0x0200000037de5708dce42f56ca1fb49fb2f34ac7f1b17d21
DELETE FROM [KeyWordsToItem] 
WHERE IdItemType = 2 AND
      IdItem IN ( 
         SELECT Id FROM [Clip]
         WHERE IdMedia = 8904 AND LSM_LouthID NOT IN ('#NCnuyFG') )     
    inputbuf
DELETE FROM [KeyWordsToItem] 
WHERE IdItemType = 2 AND
      IdItem IN ( 
         SELECT Id FROM [Clip]
         WHERE IdMedia = 8904 AND LSM_LouthID NOT IN ('#NCnuyFG') )    
   process id=processbf5018 taskpriority=0 logused=6884 waitresource=KEY: 6:72057600638255104 (810048eb4170) waittime=5000 ownerId=2999709276 transactionname=user_transaction lasttranstarted=2012-03-23T10:13:28.640 XDES=0x26f505e0 lockMode=S schedulerid=4 kpid=2488 status=suspended spid=293 sbid=0 ecid=0 priority=0 transcount=2 lastbatchstarted=2012-03-23T10:13:29.687 lastbatchcompleted=2012-03-23T10:13:29.687 hostpid=3516 loginname=EVS isolationlevel=read committed (2) xactid=2999709276 currentdb=6 lockTimeout=4294967295 clientoption1=671088672 clientoption2=128056
    executionStack
     frame procname=adhoc line=1 sqlhandle=0x020000004ccefe1488b29fbb71c97825ce7c74e9e683fd2c
DELETE FROM [KeyWordsToItem] 
WHERE IdItemType = 2 AND
      IdItem IN ( 
         SELECT Id FROM [Clip]
         WHERE IdMedia = 8905 AND LSM_LouthID NOT IN ('#NBIZhap') )     
    inputbuf
DELETE FROM [KeyWordsToItem] 
WHERE IdItemType = 2 AND
      IdItem IN (
         SELECT Id FROM [Clip]
         WHERE IdMedia = 8905 AND LSM_LouthID NOT IN ('#NBIZhap') )    
  resource-list
   keylock hobtid=72057600639696896 dbid=6 objectname=CleanEditDB.dbo.KeyWordsToItem indexname=PK_KeyWordsToItem id=lock2d9e3680 mode=U associatedObjectId=72057600639696896
    owner-list
     owner id=processbf5018 mode=U
    waiter-list
     waiter id=process8ba4d8 mode=U requestType=wait
   keylock hobtid=72057600638255104 dbid=6 objectname=CleanEditDB.dbo.Clip indexname=IX_Clip id=lock78200640 mode=X associatedObjectId=72057600638255104
    owner-list
     owner id=process8ba4d8 mode=X
    waiter-list
     waiter id=processbf5018 mode=S requestType=wait
```

My understanding is that the 2 transactions operate on 2 disjoint sets on data.

So why is there a deadlock ? 
Is this because the server takes page locks behind the scene ?

How can I prevent them to happen ?

Thanks for your help !

Here are the tables and indexes definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[KeyWordsToItem](
    [IdKeyWord] [dbo].[identifier] NOT NULL,
    [IdItem] [dbo].[identifier] NOT NULL,
    [IdItemType] [dbo].[identifier] NOT NULL,
    [PosIndex] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_KeyWordsToItem] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [IdItemType] ASC,
    [IdItem] ASC,
    [IdKeyWord] ASC,
    [PosIndex] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_KeyWordsToItem_KeyWord] ON [dbo].[KeyWordsToItem] 
(
    [IdKeyWord] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[KeyWords](
    [Id] [dbo].[identifier] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Keyword] [nvarchar](64) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_KeyWords] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Clip](
    [Id] [dbo].[identifier] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [IdMedia] [dbo].[identifier] NOT NULL,
    [TcInMedia] [dbo].[fields] NOT NULL,
    [Label] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [Duration] [dbo].[fields] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Clip] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Clip_IdMedia] ON [dbo].[Clip] 
(
    [IdMedia] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Media](
    [Id] [dbo].[identifier] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [IdMediaFileLow] [dbo].[identifier] NULL,
    [IdMediaFileHigh] [dbo].[identifier] NULL,
    [Label] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [LSM_LouthID] [nchar](8) NULL,
    [Version] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Media] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Media_IdMediaFileHigh] ON [dbo].[Media] 
(
    [IdMediaFileHigh] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Media_IdMediaFileLow] ON [dbo].[Media] 
(
    [IdMediaFileLow] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: Try to enable snapshot isolation level on the database for optimistic concurrency.

Comment: I'm no DBA so adding this as a comment rather than an answer. You seem to be deadlocking on a key (waitresource=KEY) in the KeyWordsToItem index. Getting a deadlock on key level would seem to indicate that the deletes aren't disjoint but overlap.

Comment: This is almost certainly an indexing problem.  You need to provide us with the Table definitions, including any indexes and keys (you can omit any non-involved columns, though we may need to know how big they are).  We also need to see the actual SQL being executed, because its a little hard to sort out of the Deadlock graph.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I added the tables and indexes definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have a Clustered Key on your [Clip] table.  Make the Primary Key ([Id]) Clustered.

Also, there is something wrong with your listed Table definitions.  The deadlock graph seems to think that you are querying on a LSM_LouthID column in you [Clip] table, but you only list that column in your [Media] table.

If there really *is* such a column in [Clip], then add a non-Clustered index on the [clip] table columns (IdMedia , LSM_LouthId).

I believe that these changes should make this problem go away.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In the meantime, I moved to another job, so Icannot say if your recommendations solved the issue but they definitly make sense. I forward them to the team in charge of the project.

Answer (score 3):

Two disjoint sets can still deadlock because of hash collision, see [%%LOCKRES%% Collision probability magic marker: 16,777,215](http://rusanu.com/2009/05/29/lockres-collision-probability-magic-marker-16777215/)

However your deadlock is not such a case. The deadlock involves the table `CleanEditDB.dbo.Clip` which doesn't appear anywhere in the statements yet one transaction has a S lock on it and the other transaction needs an X lock. This leads me to believe there is a cascade delete foreign key involved, or another similar 'out-of-band' mechanism involved here.  You would have to post the exact definition of the objects involved , including all indexes and all foreign keys.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added the tables and indexes definition. I think the table CleanEditDB.dbo.Clip does appear in the SELECT subquery in the deadlock graph.